# lsusb detects sd card but neither fdisk nor parted on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, sd-card, disk-formatting

I would like to open my micro SD card but it's not mounted. The SD card reader is well detected with `lsusb`:

Output of `lsusb`:

[image: Output of lsusb]

But judging by the output of dmesg, there's a problem with the card:

Output of `dmesg`:

[image: Output of dmesg]

And I can't find sdc in the output of parted:

Output of `sdc`:

[image: Output of sdc]

and the command `file` indicates that `/dev/sdc` is empty (what does that mean?):

[image: Output of file]

I think the partition table of the SD card is damaged, because it started behaving like this after a failed attempt to format it. Is there a way to mount it so that I can create a partition and use its file system?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mount to partition you run the fdisk command, what it looks like on my sd card in its reader.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:~# fdisk -l /dev/sde
Disk /dev/sde: 29.81 GiB, 32010928128 bytes, 62521344 sectors
Disk model: Storage Device  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8d99794c

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sde1         8192   532479   524288  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sde2       532480 62521343 61988864 29.6G 83 Linux
```

Now to partition you remove the -l and get something like this.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:~# fdisk /dev/sde

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): d 
Partition number (1,2, default 2): 1

Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1,3,4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-532479, default 2048): 8192
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (8192-532479, default 532479): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 256 MiB.
Partition #1 contains a vfat signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: n

Command (m for help): q
```

There I showed you how to delete a partition and create a new one as you can see I used exactly the same number as was on the drive and chose not to do anything in the end by quitting. The partition was set to type linux by default, I could have used a t followed by a 1 for the number of the partition and 0b the code for a Fat 32 like I had. When completed making the partitions you use w to write the changes to the disk then you format it depending how you want it.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:/home/zeus# mkfs.vfat /dev/sde1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:/home/zeus# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sde2
mke2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
```

The example for formatting the first partition Fat 32 and the second ext4 like in the original listing I showed you. Good luck with it I/O problems can mean the card is dead, if this does not work try it in a digital camera if it is too far gone fdisk may not be able to recover where a camera most times does not check and formats no matter the state of it.

Comment: fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: No such file or directory. The disk is not even recognized. I suspect a hardware failure in the sd card...

Comment: Yes if it will not show up it is most likely dead.